# Capturing content from a string

Tags: regex

I am attempting to parse some logs to get the specific catalog numbers for the items viewed.  I have broken out all the necessary fields and am now parsing the referer field to get the catalog id of the page viewed.

The strings are in the following formats:

```
   /catalog/AAA1111111
   /catalog/BBB-22222-1/
   /catalog/CCC-333333/XXX
   http://url/catalog/DDD-44444444
   http://url/catalog/EEE-555555555/ZZZ
```

I am using the following regex to strip out the catalog id:

```
   .*\/catalog\/([^\/]+)
```

The problem is that I cannot stop the regex from grabbing everything after the next forward slash. It looks like it is to greedy?

The results are:

```
   AAA1111111
   BBB-22222-1/
   CCC-333333/XXX
   DDD-44444444
   http:EEE-555555555/ZZZ
```

I've been banging my head on this one for a couple of hours.

I am just looking for a regex that will split out just the catalog id (the string after catalog/.)

Can anyone help guide this old coder in the proper direction?

Many thanks.

Comment: What language are you using (not all regexes are the same)?  It might be worth posting the code that uses the regex to generate the results you show...

Comment: Its a small java script that will be used in a hadoop cluster.  I was testing the regex via http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using sed

```
cat catalogs  | sed -E 's/.*\/catalog\/([^/]+)\/?.*/\1/g'
```

results in

```
AAA1111111
BBB-22222-1
CCC-333333
DDD-44444444
EEE-555555555
```

note the only modification is matching the trailing stuff

Answer (score 0):

Why using a regex when you can split on "/catalog/", take the last item then split on "/" and take the 1st item ?

In Python, this could be done like this :

```
line.split('/catalog/')[-1].split('/')[0]
```

Just wanted to point out that regexp are not the solutions for every string parsing problems.
Often, when you're faced to "greedy" parsing, doing a "manual" modification before using regexp helps

Comment: I may end up going in that direction.  For now I have to use the regex due to guidance given from above.